# How to close modal window extjs when clicking on mask?

Tags: extjs, modal-dialog, extjs4.1

If I create a modal window:

```
Ext.define('myWindow', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    alias: 'widget.myWindow',
    floating: true,
    modal: true,
    listeners:
        'onMaskClick???': { close the window }
    .....
}
```

How do I know when a user has clicked on the mask outside the window? In Sench Touch, there is a config hideOnMaskTap that lets me specify. What is the event/config for extJS?

Comment: A loadmask doesn't have a click event.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Tramway's case (sort of) works on modal or non modal windows. But not in case child components like the boundlist of a combobox float outside the windows boundaries.

However if you use modal windows anyway you can listen for a click event on the mask like this.

```
Ext.define('myWindow', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    alias: 'widget.myWindow',
    floating: true,
    modal: true,

    initComponent: function () {
        var me = this;
        me.callParent(arguments);
        me.mon(Ext.getBody(), 'click', function(el, e){
            me.close(me.closeAction);
        }, me, { delegate: '.x-mask' });
    }
});
```

Comment: This is the correct answer and very clever to use a delegate. The window must anyway be modal because otherwise it would be strange for it to close when the user interacts with another window. Modal windows have a visual cue to suggest this to the user.

Comment: shouldn't the first line of the `initComponent` function be `var me = this;` ?

Comment: Good solution, there's just one thing missing - you should extend [Ext.window.Window](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.0/#!/api/Ext.window.Window), not just the base Container, otherwise you will be missing everything from [Panel](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.0/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel) and Window classes:
`extend: 'Ext.window.Window',`

Comment: What is the tip  if you have a windows without modal, you can't use : 'x-mask'.

Comment: Like jjrv said: 'The window must anyway be modal because otherwise it would be strange for it to close when the user interacts with another window. Modal windows have a visual cue to suggest this to the user.' Why don't you want to make it modal? and if you really don't want to see the mask just set its opacity to 0

Comment: Excellent answer. I especially like the use of `mon`.

Answer (score 11):

You can listen all click events, then check if click position is out of the window

```
Ext.define('myWindow', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    alias: 'widget.myWindow',
    floating: true,
    modal: true,

    initComponent: function () {
        this.initEvents();
        this.callParent();
    },

    initEvents: function () {
        //make sure your window is rendered and have sizes and position
        if(!this.rendered) {
            this.on('afterrender', this.initEvents, this, {single: true});
            return;
        }

        this.mon(Ext.getBody(), 'click', this._checkCloseClick, this);
    }

    _checkCloseClick: function (event) {
        var cx = event.getX(), cy = event.getY(),
            box = this.getBox();

        if (cx < box.x || cx > box.x + box.width || cy < box.y || cy > box.y + box.height) {
            //clean up listener listener
            this.mun(Ext.getBody(), 'click', this._checkCloseClick, this);
            this.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have a combobox in your window the dropdownlist can be rendered outside the windows boundaries. Resulting in unwanted closing of the window when you select an item outside of the windows boundaries.

Comment: after some modification it perfectly worked for me. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this also:

```
Ext.getBody().on('click', function(e, t){
    var el = win.getEl();

    if (!(el.dom === t || el.contains(t))) {
        win.close();
    }
});
```

Comment: I like this idea! In my case I use window but without borders, etc. So this can help me hide it when it must be hidden :)

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: win is not defined

Answer (score 0):

I found adding a listener to the body and checking css classes felt a little hackey to me. You can actually override the private method `_onMaskClick` of `Ext.ZIndexManager` (see, completely not hackey). Which allows you to add your own configuration parameter (and even event) to all windows.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.ux.ZIndexManager_maskClick', {
  override: 'Ext.ZIndexManager',

  _onMaskClick: function ()
  {
    if (this.front)
    {
      var allowed = this.front.fireEvent('maskclick', this.front, this.mask);

      if (allowed !== false && this.front.closeOnMaskClick)
        this.front.close();
    }
    return this.callParent(arguments);
  },
});
```