# How to close/hide a Window when clicking outside the Window?

Tags: ext.net

I want to close a Window when clicking outside the Window,
I think I need something like a click-handler on the mask behind the window (yes its modal=true) or a "onLooseFocus"-Handler on the Window... I tried this:

```
windowX.Listeners.Show.Handler = "Ext.select('.ext-el-mask').addListener('click', function() {Ext.getCmp('windowX').hide();});";
```

But it doesn't work, also no error in Firebug so i cant find the mistake - can anyone help me?

edit: I'm using Ext.Net 2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this on the ext.net forums](http://forums.ext.net/showthread.php?17221-CLOSED-Ext-Window-Question-about-clicking-outside-a-modal-Window)

```
    <ext:Window runat="server" Modal="true">
    <Listeners>
        <Show Handler="this.mask.on('click', function () {
                            alert('I am the Mask!');
                        });"
                Single="true" />
    </Listeners>
    </ext:Window>
```

**Edit**

Since its not working, returning to extjs is the best solution, with help from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15524372/895167) the code becomes

```
    <ext:Window runat="server" Modal="true">
    <Listeners>
        <Show Handler="this.mon(Ext.getBody(), 'click', function (el, e) {
            this.close(this.closeAction);
        }, this, { delegate: '.x-mask' });"
                Single="true" />
    </Listeners>
    </ext:Window>
```

Comment: they must have changed this, doesn't work. Sorry I didn't mention my Ext.Net Version - it is 2.2